# startAngle in Arc JavaFX is not what it says

Tags: java, javafx

When I use the `Arc` class from JavaFX and set the `startAngle` property to e.g. 45 degrees, it actually draws an arc with a `startAngle` at ca 26 degrees.

How does it scale the `startAngle`-degrees?

The picture shows a screenshot from Scene Builder but when I coded it like below, it had the same result.

```
Arc arc = new Arc();
arc.setCenterX(0f);
arc.setCenterY(0f);
arc.setRadiusX(377f);
arc.setRadiusY(180f);
arc.setStartAngle(45.0f);
arc.setLength(135f);
arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
```

[image: screenshot from SceneBuilder]

Comment: Aren’t you using a circular measure?  What do you see if the arc’s radiusX and radiusY are equal?

Comment: Ah, ok, it takes the same height as a circle would have whith 45 degrees. But why is the startAngle not just the radius i drawed? Wouldn't it be more intuitive?

Comment: The startAngle is an angle along the circumference, not the angle of the radial segment leading to the starting point.  I guess ‘intuitive’ is subjective, but that is the behavior I would expect.